# sequence notation indice written twice

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

In a book I have found this notation for a sequence : $(X_n)_n$

I used to see it written like this : $(X_n)$ or $X_n$

Is it correct? And why do we rewrite $n$ twice, is there any additional information when we do so?

Answer (score 0):

The index is repeated outside of the parentheses because sometimes it is ambiguous which variable denotes the index, e.g. $(n^k)_n$ and $(n^k)_k$ are different sequences. Sometimes you even see $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ if you want to emphasise the range of indices.

Usually the index is apparent from the context, though. In the example above, $k$ or $n$ might already be defined, so the other variable must be the index. Therefore it is common to skip the repeated index, which is what you are used to: $(X_n)$.

Strictly speaking, $X_n$ does not denote the sequence but the $n$-th term of the sequence. But when no confusion arises, it is also acceptable to denote the sequence this way. The main advantage is that you can use less words when defining the sequence by saying: “Consider the sequence $X_n = n^2$.” instead of “Consider the sequence $(X_n)$ where $X_n = n^2$.” or “Consider the sequence $(X_n) = (n^2)$.” (which would be correct but many people find unnatural).